# Nested looping for simple logic parser

Tags: c++, loops, parsing, arduino

I am writing a parser for a simple programming language consisting of possibly an axis number, a two letter command, and possibly an input value. All commands are separated by a comma. I have a parser that splits the input by the delineator and runs each valid command one at a time. I'm having issues programming the looping function RP.

I could have a command like this

`MD1,TP,RP5,TT,RP10`

in which I would want it to run as

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    TT();
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        TP();
    }
}
```

So far the main parser that I have will see the first RP command and run that then see the second RP command and run it. The RP command is set to loop from the end of the last RP command giving something more like this.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    TP();
}  
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    TT();
}
```

I've tried a few different approaches, but so far no luck. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `MD1,TP,RP5,TT,RP10` shouldn't result in: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { TP(); } TT(); }`. I mean, I would expect that according to your input `TT` should be executed _after_ `RP5`.

Comment: What does `MD1` do?

Comment: Scheff: You are correct.

Comment: MD1 defines a macro such that it can be called with MS1. Essentially just stores it to called later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I considered the question a little bit too broad. On the other hand, I couldn't resist to "try out".

## Preface

First, I want to criticize (a little bit) the question title. ***simple logic parser*** sounds for me like an interpreter of [*boolean expressions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression). However, I remember that my engineering colleagues are often talking about "program logic" (and I've not yet achieved that they get rid of this). Hence, my recommendation: If you (the questioner) are talking with computer scientists, use the term "logic" sensible (or they might look confused sometimes...)

The sample code `MD1,TP,RP5,TT,RP10` looks somehow familiar to me. A short google/wikipedia research cleared my mind: The Wikipedia article [Numerical control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_control) is about CNC machines. Close to the end of the article, the programming is mentioned. (The German "sibling" article provides even more.) IMHO, the code really looks similar a bit but seems to be even simpler. (No offense – I consider it as good to keep things as simple as possible.)

The program notation which seems to be intended is somehow like [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). I wanted at least mention that term as googling for "rpn interpreter" throws a lot of sufficient hits including github sites. Actually, the description of the intended language is a little bit too short to decide certainly which existing S/W project could be appropriate.

Having said this, I want to show what I got...

## Parser

I started first with a parser (as the questioner didn't dare to expose his). This is the code of `mci1.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char uchar;

enum Token {
  TkMD = 'M' | 'D' << 8,
  TkRP = 'R' | 'P' << 8,
  TkTP = 'T' | 'P' << 8,
  TkTT = 'T' | 'T' << 8
};

inline Token tokenize(uchar c0, uchar c1) { return (Token)(c0 | c1 << 8); }

bool parse(istream &in)
{
  for (;;) {
    // read command (2 chars)
    char cmd[2];
    if (in >> cmd[0] >> cmd[1]) {
      //cout << "DEBUG: token: " << hex << tokenize(cmd[0], cmd[1]) << endl;
      switch (tokenize(cmd[0], cmd[1])) {
        case TkMD: { // MD<num>
          int num;
          if (in >> num) {
            cout << "Received 'MD" << dec << num << "'." << endl;
          } else {
            cerr << "ERROR: Number expected after 'MD'!" << endl;
            return false;
          }
        } break;
        case TkRP:  { // RP<num>
          int num;
          if (in >> num) {
            cout << "Received 'RP" << dec << num << "'." << endl;
          } else {
            cerr << "ERROR: Number expected after 'RP'!" << endl;
            return false;
          }
        } break;
        case TkTP: // TP
          cout << "Received 'TP'." << endl;
          break;
        case TkTT: // TT
          cout << "Received 'TT'." << endl;
          break;
        default:
          cerr << "ERROR: Wrong command '" << cmd[0] << cmd[1] << "'!" << endl;
          return false;
      }
    } else {
      cerr << "ERROR: Command expected!" << endl;
      return false;
    }
    // try to read separator
    char sep;
    if (!(in >> sep)) break; // probably EOF (further checks possible)
    if (sep != ',') {
      cerr << "ERROR: ',' expected!" << endl;
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  // test string
  string sample("MD1,TP,RP5,TT,RP10");
  // read test string
  istringstream in(sample);
  if (parse(in)) cout << "Done." << endl;
  else cerr << "Interpreting aborted!" << endl;
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled and tested with `g++` and `bash` in Cygwin on Windows 10:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.4.0

$ g++ -std=c++11 -o mci mci1.cc

$ ./mci
Received 'MD1'.
Received 'TP'.
Received 'RP5'.
Received 'TT'.
Received 'RP10'.
Done.

$
```

Uploaded for life demo on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/ljANSE).

I introduced the function `tokenize()` as part of an update. (I got the idea when I was tooth brushing and poring how to get rid of the ugly nested `switch`es of the previous version.) [Tokenizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization) is a common technique in parsing – however, the implementation is usually a little bit different.

Thus, the parser seems to work. Not yet the next big thing but sufficient for the next step...

## Interpreter

To interprete the parsed commands, I started to make a resp. back-end – a set of classes which may store and execute the required operations.

The `parse()` function of the first step became the `compile()` function where simple standard output was replaced by code building and nesting the operations. `mci2.cc`:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// super class of all operations
class Op {
  protected:
    Op() = default;
  public:
    virtual ~Op() = default;
    virtual void exec() const = 0;
  // disabled: (to prevent accidental usage)
    Op(const Op&) = delete;
    Op& operator=(const Op&) = delete;
};

// super class of grouping operations
class Grp: public Op {
  protected:
    vector<Op*> _pOps; // nested operations

  protected:
    Grp() = default;
    virtual ~Grp()
    {
      for (Op *pOp : _pOps) delete pOp;
    }
  public:
    void add(Op *pOp) { _pOps.push_back(pOp); }
  // disabled: (to prevent accidental usage)
    Grp(const Grp&) = delete;
    Grp& operator=(const Grp&) = delete;
};

// class for repeat op.
class RP: public Grp {
  private:
    unsigned _n; // repeat count
  public:
    RP(unsigned n): Grp(), _n(n) { }
    virtual ~RP() = default;
    virtual void exec() const
    {
      cout << "Exec. RP" << _n << endl;
      for (unsigned i = 0; i < _n; ++i) {
        for (const Op *pOp : _pOps) pOp->exec();
      }
    }
  // disabled: (to prevent accidental usage)
    RP(const RP&) = delete;
    RP& operator=(const RP&) = delete;
};

// class for TP op.
class TP: public Op {
  public:
    TP() = default;
    virtual ~TP() = default;
    virtual void exec() const
    {
      cout << "Exec. TP" << endl;
    }    
};

// class for TT op.
class TT: public Op {
  public:
    TT() = default;
    virtual ~TT() = default;
    virtual void exec() const
    {
      cout << "Exec. TT" << endl;
    }    
};

// class for MD sequence
class MD: public Grp {
  private:
    unsigned _axis;
  public:
    MD(unsigned axis): Grp(), _axis(axis) { }
    virtual ~MD() = default;
    virtual void exec() const
    {
      cout << "Exec. MD" << _axis << endl;
      for (const Op *pOp : _pOps) pOp->exec();
    }
};

typedef unsigned char uchar;

enum Token {
  TkMD = 'M' | 'D' << 8,
  TkRP = 'R' | 'P' << 8,
  TkTP = 'T' | 'P' << 8,
  TkTT = 'T' | 'T' << 8
};

inline Token tokenize(uchar c0, uchar c1) { return (Token)(c0 | c1 << 8); }

MD* compile(istream &in)
{
  MD *pMD = nullptr;
  stack<Op*> pOpsNested;
#define ERROR \
  delete pMD; \
  while (pOpsNested.size()) { delete pOpsNested.top(); pOpsNested.pop(); } \
  return nullptr
  for (;;) {
    // read command (2 chars)
    char cmd[2];
    if (in >> cmd[0] >> cmd[1]) {
      //cout << "DEBUG: token: " << hex << tokenize(cmd[0], cmd[1]) << dec << endl;
      switch (tokenize(cmd[0], cmd[1])) {
        case TkMD: { // MD<num>
          int num;
          if (in >> num) {
            if (pMD) {
              cerr << "ERROR: Unexpected command 'MD" << num << "'!" << endl;
              ERROR;
            }
            pMD = new MD(num);
          } else {
            cerr << "ERROR: Number expected after 'MD'!" << endl;
            ERROR;
          }
        } break;
        case TkRP:  { // RP<num>
          int num;
          if (in >> num) {
            if (!pMD) {
              cerr << "ERROR: Unexpected command 'RP" << num << "'!" << endl;
              ERROR;
            }
            RP *pRP = new RP(num);
            while (pOpsNested.size()) {
              pRP->add(pOpsNested.top());
              pOpsNested.pop();
            }
            pOpsNested.push(pRP);
          } else {
            cerr << "ERROR: Number expected after 'RP'!" << endl;
            ERROR;
          }
        } break;
        case TkTP: { // TP
          if (!pMD) {
            cerr << "ERROR: Unexpected command 'TP'!" << endl;
            ERROR;
          }
          pOpsNested.push(new TP());
        } break;
        case TkTT: { // TT
          if (pOpsNested.empty()) {
            cerr << "ERROR: Unexpected command 'TT'!" << endl;
            ERROR;
          }
          pOpsNested.push(new TT());
        } break;
        default:
          cerr << "ERROR: Wrong command '" << cmd[0] << cmd[1] << "'!" << endl;
          ERROR;
      }
    } else {
      cerr << "ERROR: Command expected!" << endl;
      ERROR;
    }
    // try to read separator
    char sep;
    if (!(in >> sep)) break; // probably EOF (further checks possible)
    if (sep != ',') {
      cerr << "ERROR: ',' expected!" << endl;
      ERROR;
    }
  }
#undef ERROR
  assert(pMD != nullptr);
  while (pOpsNested.size()) {
    pMD->add(pOpsNested.top());
    pOpsNested.pop();
  }
  return pMD;
}

int main()
{
  // test string
  string sample("MD1,TP,RP3,TT,RP2");
  // read test string
  istringstream in(sample);
  MD *pMD = compile(in);
  if (!pMD) {
    cerr << "Interpreting aborted!" << endl;
    return 1;
  }
  // execute sequence
  pMD->exec();
  delete pMD;
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Again, I compiled and tested with `g++` and `bash` in Cygwin on Windows 10:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o mci mci2.cc

$ ./mci
Exec. MD1
Exec. RP2
Exec. TT
Exec. RP3
Exec. TP
Exec. TP
Exec. TP
Exec. TT
Exec. RP3
Exec. TP
Exec. TP
Exec. TP

$
```

Uploaded for life demo on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/FSJUHr).

The trick with the nesting is rather simple done in the `compile()` function:

- commands `TP` and `TT` are added to a temporary stack `pOpsNested`
- for command `RP`, all collected operations are added to the `RP` instance popping the `pOpsNested` stack (and thus reversing their order),
  afterwards, the `RP` instance itself is pushed into `pOpsNested` stack instead
- finally the contents of buffer `pOpsNested` is added to sequence `MD` (as these are the top-level ops).

Comment: Just made an update. Btw. reading your question again, I realized that `MD1` should be an optional command. In my sample, it is mandatory as I didn't notice before.